# AFNetworking and URL construction - can I change the behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm busy with web service and an iOS app. So far I haven't had that many issues. However, there is a web service that needs the final URL request to be in a certain format. Something along the lines of:

> ...?IncludedUserIds[]=1357213,286476&..

These parameters are constructed from an NSDictionary and NSString. Now when I add the comma - the end URL that makes the request ends up like this:

> ..?IncludedUserIds=%5B%5D1357213%2C286476&...

It seems that `AFNetworking 2.0` has converted the square brackets into `=%5B%5D` and the comma into: `%2C`

Obviously, the web service has no idea what this means and fails.

Is there a way to keep the final Url as I need it to be? Why do these conversions happen and where can I learn more about this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking keep the final url encoded, that is the best way, since you could have special characters in you query string that could break all. Instead, you should decode the url server side, for example in PHP you have methods, like `urldecode` or `rawurldecode` (eg: 'foo%20bar%40baz' ->'foo bar@baz'), or in ASP it should be kept automatically.

Hope it helps

Comment: You're absolutely right. The issue is actually server side and not iOS side. Will need to try fix it somehow.

Comment: @Tander Time to start blaming the service team eh :P

Comment: Well, the web service needs a POST message for it to work. I'm doing a GET request - so there is an issue somewhere.

Comment: If I could fix it - I'd love to. But I think I'm out of my depth here